# Напишите программу, которая загадывает случайное число от 0 до 15 включительно

Tags: python

Не могу понять как привести код в тот вид, который нужно. Есть задача:

> Напишите программу, которая загадывает случайное число от 0 до 15 включительно, и просит пользователя угадать его с трех попыток.
>
> При каждом вводе пользователем числа программа отвечает «тепло», если введенное число отличается от загаданного на 2 или меньше и «холодно», если на 3 и больше.
>
> В каждом ответе программа также подсказывает, больше или меньше введенное число, чем загаданное (выводит на экран "нужно больше" или "нужно меньше").

Не могу понять как сделать "тепло" при 2-х попытках и "холодно" при 3-х.
Мой код:

```
from random import random
n = round(random() * 15)
i = 1
print("Компьютер загадал число от 0 до 15. Отгадайте его. У вас 3 попытки")
while i <= 3:
    u = int(input(str(i) + '-я попытка: '))
    if u > n:
        print('Много')
    elif u < n:
        print('Мало')
    else:
        print('Вы угадали с %d-й попытки' % i)
        break
    i += 1
else:
    print('Вы исчерпали 3 попытки. Было загадано', n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint
n = randint(0, 15)
i = 1
print("Компьютер загадал число от 0 до 15. Отгадайте его. У вас 3 попытки")
while i <= 3:
    u = int(input(str(i) + '-я попытка: '))
    if u > n:
        print('Много')
        print("Но тепло" if abs(n - u) <= 2 else "И холодно")
    elif u < n:
        print('Мало')
        print("Но тепло" if abs(n - u) <= 2 else "И холодно")
    else:
        print('Вы угадали с %d-й попытки' % i)
        break
    i += 1
else:
    print("Вы не смогли угадать число", n)
```

Comment: Нет. Компьютер загадал число от 1 до 16.

Comment: Поправил, просто думал, что правая граница не включается @МихаилМуругов

Comment: Всё ещё не от 0 до 15.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, можете по-подробней, я ведь не экстрасенс

Comment: [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) - Return a random integer *N* such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.